# Missing table [rev_info] after bump liquibase version, spring data envers

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, liquibase

I have problem with my project after bump liquibase version to 4.9.1.
There is error:

> BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
> 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
> Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException:
> Schema-validation: missing table [rev_info]

There is **spring-data-envers** version 2.5.5

Everyting works fine with liquibse 4.4
But when I change to newest version (4.9.1) applicantion do not start.

I have revision entity - **RevInfo** and changeset to create this table
create table public.rev_info

> (
> id                     INTEGER NOT NULL,
> timestamp              BIGSERIAL,
> CONSTRAINT rev_pk PRIMARY KEY (id) );

**ddl-auto** is set **validate**

Answer (score 0):

The Java Revisited blog had a solution for this error [on their site here](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/09/2-reasons-of-orgspringframeworkbeansfactory-beanCreationException-Error-creating-bean-with-name.html#axzz7SueUW5ZK), but to summarize:

There could be numerous reasons why Spring was unable to create a bean with name X, but the reason can be found on the detailed stack trace. This error always has some underlying cause e.g. a ClassNotFoundException or a NoClassDefFoundError, which potentially signals a missing JAR file in the classpath.

In short, you should always give a detailed look at the stack trace of your error message and find out the exact cause of "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating a bean with name" error. The solution would vary accordingly.